# free subgroups of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z[i]})$

Tags: matrices, number-fields, free-groups

The group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ contains many free subgroups, for example all of the principal congruence subgroups for $n\geq 3$ and the subgroup $\left\langle \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
2 & 1
\end{array}\right)\right\rangle $ which is almost the principal congruence subgroup for n=2, and more over it has a finite index in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. In addition, when projecting $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ onto $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p)$, the restriction to these subgroups is also surjective as long as $p \nmid n$.

Is a similar phenomena true for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[i])$, or more generally when we substitute $\mathbb{Z}$ with the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_k$ for some number field $k$?

EDIT: I look for free subgroups which are hopefully finite index (for example the congruence subgroups). Since finite index means they are a lattice, this enables me to count the number of lattice points in a ball of radius R asymptotically as R goes to infinity. If this is not possible, I would like to find free subgroups which are large in the sense that they have large growth.

Comment: You should be more specific, the answer depends on the exact meaning of "phenomena". Are you asking for existence of free subgroups? Subgroups generated by powers of two given unipotent elements not generating a solvable subgroup? Then yes. Are you asking for free subgroups of finite index? Then no (ever).

Comment: A possible interpretation of the question is whether every lattice contains a profinitly dense free group. Then the answer should be yes, but I am not sure what is the right refernce (Margulis-Soifer?).

Comment: @Misha I was hoping that the principal congruence subgroups in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[i])$ would be free, or at least virtually free. Why aren't there any finite index free subgroups?

Comment: @Prometheus: One way to see this is to observe that $SL(2, Z[i])$ contains free abelian subgroups of rank 2.

Comment: Prometheus, just to emphasize @Misha 's answer, you should know that for every number field $k$ other then $\mathbb{Q}$, $\Gamma=\text{SL}_2(\mathcal{O})$ will not be virtually free. Nevertheless, $\Gamma$ will contain "large" free subgroups, for various notions of "largeness". However, I suppose that these large free subgroups will give you nothing but obvious lower bounds for lattice points counting problems.

Comment: As Misha and Uri Bader have observed, you cannot get free subgroups of finite index. If you view $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[i])$ as a subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ the latter sen as a REAL group, then free subgroups of infinite index which are Zariski dense in the real group do exist (again, by Margulis Soifer, as referenced by Uri Bader, if you like). Then a result of Nori and Weisfeiler says that these free subgroups surject onto $SL_2(O_K/p)$ for any non-zero prime ideal in $O_K$ where $O_K$ is the ring of integers in the imaginary quadratic $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: As was mentioned earlier, there is no free subgroup of finite index in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[i])$: my favorite proof uses virtual cohomological dimension, which is 2 here (as opposed to 1 for virtually free groups). See the wonderful paper by J.-P. Serre, "Cohomologie des groupes discrets", especially Proposition 21.
Question for Prometheus: what do you mean by "free subgroups which are large in the sense that they have large growth"?

Comment: @AlainValette By the growth I meant the number of points in a ball of radius R as R goes to infinity, for some given matrix norm. In the $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ case it grows as $\Theta(R^2)$ (for any fixed finite index subgroup).